# Is there an efficient command for listing the header of a particular file in tar.bz2 without uncompressing/extracting?

Tags: tar, compression

I was working with a `data.tar.bz2`, which contains lots of other big files of the scale of a few hundred Gigabytes. I just wanted to see the `header` (first line) of a particular file `file-of-interest`, to see what is the `header` of `file-of-interest`.

Until now, I have just found how to list the files of `tar.bz2` but no way of `cat` the contents of `file-of-interest` contained in the archive. Is there an efficient way to do so  **without uncompressing/extracting** considering files contained are too big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do anything without uncompressing (at least partially) the archive. 
However, you can extract only the file you're interested in directly to stdout. Example:

```
tar -xOf data.tar.bz2 file-of-interest | head -n1
```

Comment: Works great. This is what I needed.

Comment: If the file is toward start of archive, then the un-compression may stop early.